# Extract values from a matrix in R

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix, subset, distance

I have a large matrix and I wanto extract values >0 and <5. I create this matrix with function

"dist" of package "proxy". The output is an object of type crossmat.

```
a <- df1
b <- df2
```

where df1 and df2 are df with coordinates x,y,z. then I used

```
 library (proxy)
    dm <-  dist(a, b , method = "euclidean")
```

now I want to extract values from this matrix and to have them in a df with 3 columns, for example.

```
index (row) index (column)   value 
     256          544        3.5489


head (result) 
     row col    value
3672 307 192 4.963545
3673 308 192 4.848763
3672 307 193 4.769458
3673 308 193 4.645692
3674 309 193 4.889749
3672 307 194 4.125620
```

The number I need is 3672 and not 307, for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using `which` with `arr.ind = TRUE` :

```
mat <- which(dm > 0 & dm < 5, arr.ind = TRUE)
result <- cbind(mat, value = dm[mat])
result
```

Comment: it works but rows of my matrix started from 3336, instead in the result I got numbers as 197 and more in the rox index column

Comment: I added the head(result) in the question. Also, result is an atomic vector and not a df

Comment: @Nancy To get rownames as first column you can do `result[, 1] <- rownames(result)`. If you want to convert it to dataframe you can do `result <- data.frame(result)`. If this still doesn't work for you as expected could you provide an example dataset for us to test our answer?

Comment: I have another question about loops, can you help me? I will buy you a coffee ;)